# Counting number of draws needed to obtain a set of items

Tags: probability, distributions

I have a bag with three type of items: A, B, C.
The items have a probability of appearance of 0.05, 0.35, 0.60 respectively.

Once a draw is done, the quantity received is determined with another draw from a 'bag of quantities'.
There are three quantities: 1, 5, and 10.
With the following probabilities: 0.10, 0.40, 0.50 respectively.

Is there a way to answer the question "draws needed to obtain 20 units of A"?

Ideally, without quantities, I could have grouped the bag into A-items and no-A-items, and answer directly making use of the binomial distribution.

Can a similar thing be done with quantities involved?

In a similar question, I have been referred to the Coupon collector problem. While interesting, if I understood it properly, it does not answer this question.

Answer (score 3):

**Let's begin by restating the problem more simply.**

At the end of one draw you have observed a quantity $X$ in the set $\{0,1,5,10\}.$ You have provided enough information to obtain their chances:

- The quantity $0$ is observed when $A$ is not drawn, which has chance $p(0)=19/20.$
- The quantity $1$ is observed when $A$ is drawn and (independently of that) the value $1$ is pulled out of the second bag with probability $1/10.$ Thus, the chance of a $1$ is $p(1) = 1/20 \times 1/10.$
- Similarly, $p(5)=1/20\times 4/10$ and $p(10)=1/20\times 5/10.$

After $n=0, 1, 2,\ldots $ draws where quantities $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ have been independently observed, you will have accumulated the sum of your observations, $S_n = X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n.$ The number of draws $N$ needed for that sum to equal or exceed the target $T=20$ is a random variable.  **What is its expected value?**

**More generally,** given a probability distribution $p$ for the integral values $0,1,\ldots,M;$ a sequence of independent random variables $(X_i)$ that follow that distribution; and a target $T,$ we may define $N$ to be the first $n$ for which $S_n\ge T$ and ask for the expected value of $N$, $E[N].$

---

**This problem can be solved recursively** by defining the sequence $(f_k)$ of expected numbers of draws needed to reach or exceed $T$ *beginning with the values $T-k.$*

Obviously when $k\le 0,$ $f_k=0$ because the target $T$ has already been reached.  For positive $k$ consider what can happen on the next draw.  Its value can be any integer between $0$ and $M$ inclusive, taking value $i$ with probability $p(i).$  At this point one more draw has been made, increasing the current value from $T-k$ to $T-k+i.$  Thus

$$f_k = 1 + p(0) f_k + \sum_{i=1}^M p(i) f_{k-i},$$

allowing $f_k$ to be expressed in terms of the $M$ preceding values in terms of constants $\alpha$ and $\beta_1, \beta_2, \ldots, \beta_M$ as

$$f_k = \frac{1}{1-p(0)} + \sum_{i=1}^M \frac{p(i)}{1-p(0)} f_{k-i} = \alpha + \sum_{i=1}^M \beta_i f_{k-i}.$$

**By applying this recursion $T$ times for $k=1, 2, \ldots, T,$ we may compute the answer $f_{T}.$**

To see how simple and fast this can be, here is a working `R` solution.  Its input is the vector `p` = $p(0), p(1), \ldots, p(M)$ of probabilities and the target value.  It initializes an array `x` to hold the values $f(1-M), f(2-M), \ldots, f(0), f(1), f(2), \ldots, f(T),$ and then applies the recursion to compute $f(1)$ through $f(T)$:

```
# Initialize the array of expected values.
m <- length(p)-1
x <- c(rep(0, m), rep(NA_integer_, target))
names(x) <- seq.int(target+m)-m

# Perform the recursion.
r <- function(x) (1 + sum(p[-1]*rev(x))) / (1 - p[1])
for (i in 1:target) x[m+i] <- r(x[1:m + i - 1])

# Display the entire array (only the last element is needed).
round(x, 1)
```

For the data in the question the output is a row of values of $k$ above a row of values of $f_k:$

> ```
>   -9   -8   -7   -6   -5   -4   -3   -2   -1    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20 
>  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 20.0 22.0 22.2 22.2 22.2 30.2 31.8 32.1 32.1 32.1 45.3 48.3 48.8 48.8 48.8 58.1 61.0 61.6 61.7 61.8
> ```

The last element of `x`, $61.7560991680985,$ is the computed expectation $f_{20}.$

---

**For larger targets there's a faster way.**  These recursions have formulas of the form

$$f_k = \phi_0(k-k_0)^s + \sum_{i=1}^M \phi_i \lambda_i^{k-k_0}$$

where $s$ is an integer between $0$ and $M-1$ (equal to $1$ in this application), $k_0$ is an offset just to get the indexing correct, and the $\lambda_i$ and $\phi_i$ are suitable numbers (which may be, and often are, complex).  The $\lambda_i$ are roots of a polynomial determined by the recursion coefficients and the $\phi_i$ are determined by the starting values of the sequence.  For instance, $f_{10^{30}},$ which would be impossible to compute *via* the recursion, is equal to $2.8169014084507 \times 10^{30}$ (in double precision).

One principal advantage of obtaining such a formula is to obtain a good understanding of how $f_k$ behaves as $k$ grows.  One of the $\lambda$ will equal $1$ (let this be $\lambda_1$ and all the others will be smaller than that in size.  For large $k,$ this yields the approximation

$$f_k \approx \phi_0(k-k_0)^s + \phi_1.$$

[image: Figure]

That is, **for large targets, each step takes you $E[X]$ closer to the target on average,** which is an intuitively obvious result.  For smallish targets like $T=20$ this isn't too far off: $20\times 200/71 = 56.33803$ is a little smaller than the correct value, but it's within 90% of it.

Indeed, in the present case $k_0=-10,$ $s=1,$

$$\phi_0 = \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^M i p(i)} = \frac{1}{1/200 + 4/200\times 5 + 5/200\times 10} = \frac{200}{71} \approx 2.8169014084507$$

is the reciprocal of the expectation of $X,$ and $\phi_1 = -17.655227.$

---

#### Code

The following `R` code implements three solution methods: solution of the recurrence equation, direct recursion, and simulation.  The recurrence solution is coded more generally than needed: it should work for any linear recurrence, no matter how it arises.

```R
#
# Solve linear recurrences of the form
# f(k) = a + (f(k-1), f(k-2), ..., f(k-p)) * (b(1), b(2), ..., b(p))
# with starting values f(offset+1), f(offset+2), ..., f(offset+p).
#
lrsolve <- function(f, b, a=0, off=0, tol=1.0e-12) {
  p <- length(b)
  #
  # Reduce to the homogeneous recurrence.  The solution will be
  # f(k) = f_(k) + gamma * k^s where f_ satisfies the homogeneous equation.
  #
  if (a!=0) {
    k <- p+1 - seq.int(p)
    for (s in seq.int(p)-1) {
      gamma <- zapsmall(c(a, (p+1)^s - sum(b * k^s)))[2]
      if (gamma != 0.0) break
    }
    gamma <- a / gamma
    f0 <- f - seq.int(p)^s * gamma
  } else {
    gamma <- 0.0
    s <- 0
    f0 <- f
  }
  #
  # Solve the homogeneous recurrence.
  #
  lambda <- polyroot(c(-rev(b), 1))
  lambda <- lambda[order(Mod(lambda), decreasing=TRUE)]
  if(all(abs(Im(lambda)) <= tol * Mod(lambda))) lambda <- Re(lambda)

  A <- outer(seq.int(p), lambda, function(i, x) x^i)
  phi <- solve(A, f0)
  #
  # Ensure that values are of the type of the initial values.
  #
  if (all(f == Re(f))) {
    nice <- Re
    type <- "Real"
  } else {
    nice <- identity
    type <- ""
  }
  #
  # Create the function.
  #
  if (a != 0) {
    g <- Vectorize(function(k) nice(sum(phi * lambda^(k+off)) + gamma*(k+off)^s))
  } else {
    g <- Vectorize(function(k) nice(sum(phi * lambda^(k+off))))
  }
  return(list(f=g,  # Function to find values directly
              # Parameters of the function:
              roots=lambda,      
              coefficients=phi,
              gamma=gamma,
              power=s,
              offset=off,
              type=type,
              # Copies of input data:
              recursion=b,
              constant=a,
              start=f))
}
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#
# Set up the problem.
#
values <- c(0,1,5,10)                  # Non-negative integers, any order
probs <- c(19/20, 1/20 * c(1,4,5)/10)  # Their relative probabilities
target <- 20
#-- Construct the p.g.f. as an array `p` of probabilities.
p <- rep(0, 1 + max(values))
p[values+1] <- probs
p <- p / sum(p)
#
# Solve it.
#
f <- lrsolve(rep(0, length(p)-1), p[-1]/(1-p[1]), a=1/(1-p[1]), off=length(p)-1)
print(f$f(1e30), digits=16) # An example of using the result of `lrsolve`.

#-- Plot the solution out to a little (20) beyond the target value.
plot(0:(target+20), f$f(0:(target+20)), pch=21, bg="Gray",
     xlab="k", ylab=expression(f[k]),
     main="Actual and Approximate Expectations")

#-- Overplot the asymptotic solution as a line.
abline(a=Re(f$coefficients[1]) + f$gamma * f$offset, b=f$gamma, lwd=2)
#
# Solve via direct recursion (for smallish target values).
#
m <- length(p)-1
x <- c(rep(0, m), rep(NA_integer_, target))
names(x) <- seq.int(target+m)-m
r <- function(x) (1 + sum(p[-1]*rev(x))) / (1 - p[1])
for (i in 1:target) x[m+i] <- r(x[1:m + i - 1])
(round(x, 1)) # Prints array `x`
#
# Simulate the process and compare to the `lrsolve` solution.
# Z-values in the interval [-2, 2] denote good agreement.
# This should take less than a second.
#
n.sim <- 1e5
#-- Empirically discover how many draws to make in each iteration.
nmax <- ceiling(2*f$f(target))
repeat {
  x <- replicate(ceiling(n.sim/50), {
    which.min(cumsum(sample(values, nmax, replace=TRUE, prob=probs)) < target)
  })
  q <- mean(x>=nmax)
  nmax <- ceiling(max(x) * log(0.5/n.sim) / log(max(q, 0.5/length(x))))
  if (q == 0) break
}
#-- Now perform the simulation.
x <- replicate(n.sim, {
  which.min(cumsum(sample(values, nmax, replace=TRUE, prob=probs)) < target)
})
if (max(x) >= nmax) {
  maxcount <- sum(x >= nmax)
  warning("Mean may be underestimated; max reached ", maxcount, 
  " time", ifelse(maxcount==1, "", "s"), ".")
}
# hist(x)
se <- sd(x) / sqrt(length(x))
(c(Mean=mean(x), SE=se, Z=(mean(x) - f$f(target))/se))
```